# How to find out that I have called Child.parent_funcn through Child but not through Parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Here is an example in easy form what I am trying to achieve.

```
class Parent:
     def abc():
         pass

class Child(Parent):
     def pqr():
         pass
    
Child.abc
<function Parent.abc()>

Child.abc.__qualname__
'Parent.abc'

figure_out_class_from_class_func(class_func):
   ...
   derive class from class_func.__qualname__
   return class

figure_out_class_from_class_func(Child.abc) returns -> Parent. 
Actually I want it to return Child as actually I am passing Child class.
```

So basically `__qualname__` is not my friend here. Is it anyhow possible to figure out actual class rather than the parent class(where function is implemented) using Class.function ?

EDIT:
bit better example:

```
class Parent():
     def __init__(self):
         print(self.x)
     def parent_func1(self):
         pass


class Child(Parent):
     x=1

     def __init__(self):
         print(self.x)

     def child_func1(self):
         pass



def special_function(class_func):
     func_module = inspect.getmodule(class_func)
     class_name = getattr(class_func, "__qualname__", None).split(".")[0]
     class_obj = getattr(func_module, class_name)
     class_obj()

Now calling special_function(Child.child_func1) is fine-> print 1

But special_function(Child.parent_func1) gives error:

ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

      1 class Parent():
      2      def __init__(self):
----> 3          print(self.x)
      4      def parent_func1(self):
      5          pass

AttributeError: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Is there any way to find out that I have called Child.parent_funcn through Child but not through Parent ?

Comment: What's the context - why do you need to know where the method was defined?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's bit complicated. In parent I am using typing.Generic[T], and I am defining TypeVar in Child class. now when I am trying to pass Child.parent_function, T is not defined and it's throwing error. I have added another example to make it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: The fact that you retrieved `Child.abc` through `Child` doesn't mean that the object itself is in any way associated with `Child`. You can't do this for the same reason you can't distinguish `2+2` and `1+3`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I understand what is happening here and why it's behaving like this. I am just trying to ask is there any way to find out that I have called Child.abc through Child but not through Parent ? :))

Comment: You might be able to do something with “is” because Child.abc *is* Parent.abc in your example, but if Child class defined its own version of abc then Child.abc is not Parent.abc

Comment: @eemz this wont work. There are many subclasses. I dont want to implement the function(abc here) in every class :(

Comment: Your example seems to have no connection to what you described above; there are no type annotations in it.